Plugin/Module Development - How to stop all further processing?
So, I want to write a plugin/module that, when certain requirements are met, the plugin stops all further processing and returns a blank page.
For my needs, the use case for this can be one of two things:

referrer = "..."
user agent = "..." (think of ai bots or certain crawlers)

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there an API call to end all processing?

You could create a Plugin that is triggered by onAfterInitialise. https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterInitialise
Within your Plugin you would check for the 'certain requirements' from $_SERVER by using the Joomla Input functionality. https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput
When our condition is met then issue a PHP exit() or die() to stop processing and not return anything to the caller. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Thanks! That sounds like the perfect solution. I'll work on it later this week and put it up on github along with my other module.
